# Laravel and displaying errors in Placeholder

Tags: laravel, placeholder

I have a question regarding error displaying in laravel. So I want errors to be displayed in placeholders. I have done it, however, there is another problem. When I open the page I do not see placeholders so the user cannot get which input is for name and surname and etc.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/signup.css')}}">

</head>
<body>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <form action="{{url('/register')}}" method='post'>
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <input name='name' id='name'value='@if(!$errors->first("name")){{old("name")}}@endif' placeholder="{{$errors->first('name')}}">
        <input name='surname'  value='@if(!$errors->first("surname")){{old("surname")}}@endif' placeholder="{{$errors->first('surname')}}">
        <input name='email'    value='@if(!$errors->first("email")){{old("email")}}@endif' placeholder="{{$errors->first('email')}}">
        <input name='age'      value='@if(!$errors->first("age")){{old("age")}}@endif' placeholder="{{$errors->first('age')}}">
        <input name='password' value='@if(!$errors->first("password")){{old("password")}}@endif' type='password' placeholder='{{$errors->first("password")}}'>
        <input name='confirm'  value='@if(!$errors->first("confirm")){{old("confirm")}}@endif' type='password' placeholder='{{$errors->first("confirm")}}'>
        <button class='btn btn-danger'>Save</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update

```
 <input name='name' id='name'value='@if(!$errors->first("name")){{old("name")}}@endif' placeholder="{{$errors->first('name')}}">
```

to

```
 <input name='name' id='name'value='@if(!$errors->first("name")){{old("name")}}@endif' placeholder="{{$errors->has('name') ? $errors->first('name') : 'Name' }}">
```

Same way update for other input tags too.

Comment: Glad to help you. Please accept it as answer so it can help others